# Splitting an array into subarrys so that we have minimum number of subarrays with sum of elements < k

Tags: arrays, r, algorithm

I have an array with the following elements: 
`a <- c(2, 2.99, 3.95, 3, 2, 2, 2, 9.95, 9, 16.89, 8.99, 15, 15, 15, 14, 14, 16.14, 16.14, 16.14, 15.14)`

I'm looking for a way to split this array into the minimum number of subarrays such that the sum of values within each subarray is less than 20. 
I tried to solve this by sorting them in ascending order and starting by grouping smaller values first, but I don't think that is the best (or accurate) way to solve this.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, sorry about that. i've modified it.

Comment: Also this exact issue over at compsci - https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85491/algorithm-to-split-an-array-into-minimal-number-of-subarrays-where-sum-of-their

Comment: And more useful stuff -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467579/solving-task-scheduling-or-bin-packing-optimizations-in-r

Comment: I think two important/salient points to take from the other questions' comments are: "bin packing" and "NP hard".

Comment: Can there be negative values also in your input ? Also sorting won't help, that will mess up the order of elements because you want subarrays.

Comment: @SomeDude there are no negative values

Comment: A "subarray" is typically defined as contiguous. Is that the case here?

Comment: If "subarrays" are not contiguous then that is NP-hard.