# Split into groups based on (multiple) conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have set of marbles, of different colors and weights, and I want to split them into groups based on their weight and color.

The conditions are:

1. A group cannot weigh more than 100 units
2. A group cannot have more than 5 different-colored marbles.

A reproducible example:

```
marbles <- data.frame(color=sample(1:20, 20), weight=sample(1:40, 20, replace=T))

   color weight
1      1     22
2     15     33
3     13     35
4     11     13
5      6     26
6      8     15
7     10      3
8     16     22
9     14     21
10     3     16
11     4     26
12    20     30
13     9     31
14     2     16
15     7     12
16    17     13
17    19     19
18     5     17
19    12     12
20    18     40
```

And what I want is this group column:

```
   color weight group
1      1     22     1
2     15     33     1
3     13     35     1
4     11     13     2
5      6     26     2
6      8     15     2
7     10      3     2
8     16     22     2
9     14     21     3
10     3     16     3
11     4     26     3
12    20     30     3
13     9     31     4
14     2     16     4
15     7     12     4
16    17     13     4
17    19     19     4
18     5     17     5
19    12     12     5
20    18     40     5
```

TIA.

Comment: This sounds like a "bin-packing" (aka "backpack" or even "knapsack", I think) problem, you will need to research optimization to get that right.

Comment: Do you have any condition for minimum number of colors

Comment: Possibilities (unverified, I don't use them): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbp/, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mknapsack/, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10467579/3358272

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below isn't an *optimal* assignment to the groups, it just does it sequentially through the data frame. It's uses `rowwise` and might not be the most efficient way as it's not a `vectorized` approach.

```
library(dplyr)

marbles <- data.frame(color=sample(1:20, 20), weight=sample(1:40, 20, replace=T))
```

Below I create a `rowwise` function which we can apply using `dplyr`

```
assign_group <- function(color, weight) {
  # Conditions
  clists = append(color_list, color)
  sum_val = group_sum + weight
  num_colors = length(unique(color_list))

  assign_condition = (sum_val <= 100 & num_colors <= 5)
  #assign globals
  cval <- if(assign_condition) clists else c(color)
  sval <- ifelse(assign_condition, sum_val, weight)
  gval <- ifelse(assign_condition, group_number, group_number + 1)
  assign("color_list", cval, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  assign("group_sum", sval, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  assign("group_number", gval, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  res = group_number
  return(res)
}
```

I then setup a few `global` variables to track the allocation of the marbles to each group.

```
# globals
color_list <<- c()
group_sum <<- 0
group_number <<- 1
```

Finally run this function using `mutate`

```
test <- marbles %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(group = assign_group(color,weight)) %>% data.frame()
```

Which results in the below

```
 color weight group
1      6     27     1
2     12     16     1
3     15     32     1
4     20     25     1
5     19      5     2
6      2     21     2
7     16     39     2
8     17      4     2
9     11     16     2
10     7      7     3
11    10      5     3
12     1     30     3
13    13      7     3
14     9     39     3
15    14      7     4
16     8     17     4
17    18      9     4
18     4     36     4
19     3      1     4
20     5      3     5
```

And seems to meet the constraints

```
test %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(tot_w = sum(weight), n_c = length(unique(color)) )

  group tot_w   n_c
  <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1   100     4
2     2    85     5
3     3    88     5
4     4    70     5
5     5     3     1
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R you could write a recursive function as shown below:

```
create_group = function(df,a){
  if(missing(a)) a = cumsum(df$weight)%/%100
  b = !ave(df$color,a,FUN=seq_along)%%6
  d = ave(df$weight,a+b,FUN=cumsum)>100
  a = a+b+d
  if (any(b|d)) create_group(df,a) else cbind(df,group = a+1)
}

create_group(df)
   color weight group
1      1     22     1
2     15     33     1
3     13     35     1
4     11     13     2
5      6     26     2
6      8     15     2
7     10      3     2
8     16     22     2
9     14     21     3
10     3     16     3
11     4     26     3
12    20     30     3
13     9     31     4
14     2     16     4
15     7     12     4
16    17     13     4
17    19     19     4
18     5     17     5
19    12     12     5
20    18     40     5
```